# CiviVolunteer easy way to text a reminder to volunteer with their shift time

Tags: civivolunteer

Running CiviVoluteer on Wordpress and wanting to send a text via a reminder to a volunteer with their shift date and time. Using the integration set up through Events but when volunteers sign up they are not being registered for event. Therefore sending reminders doesn't work because I only have the choice to i can only choose recipients from "Participant type" (e.g. registered). Also for the text itself there doesn't seem to be tokens for any of the civivolunteer fields besides "Camera Skill Level". i would like to include Volunteer "Project Tile", "Volunteer Role" "Volunteer Opportunity Time". Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct, the event integration does not include automatically creating participant records for volunteers. If you need participant records, you should have them register, instead of using the volunteer sign-up.

If you don't really need the participant record, you can easily achieve the rest of your needs.

Just use Scheduled reminders to send an SMS relative to the volunteer Activity. It is not true that you can only select Participants for the schedued reminders. You can use the activity to trigger the reminder.

Cheers